# Jenkins Run/Replay permission missing even though authenticated users are allowed to do everything

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins 2.319.2 installation and I want to use the replay feature to get my pipeline running. However, it doesn't seem to work anymore. It tells me that I'm missing the Run/Replay permission, so I can only run the pipeline, but not modify the pipeline script. Looking at the Security configuration, I see that authenticated users (we use LDAP) are allowed to do anything, we even have anonymous read access on. Why can't I replay?

Comment: Did you get an answer? I can't edit for a replay even though I'm an admin.

Comment: @mjaggard: Sorry, no. My need to replay has vanished before I got around to digging further, so I really can't help you here.

Comment: Thanks. I'm really close to giving up on Jenkins now.

Comment: @mjaggard I feel you. I wish there was some viable alternative, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: @mjaggard [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74900644/5234788) may be of use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is (very) likely related to a syntax error in the script. I had the same error (`Allows you to run a Pipeline build again. (Without the Run/Replay permission, you are not permitted to modify the Pipeline script.`) but it resolved itself after I checked the console log and found a typo which blocked the `Jenkinsfile` from being properly parsed. The build with the corrected `Jenkinsfile` could be replayed.

See [Replay Limitations](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/#limitations) in the documentation.

In short: the error message seems misleading..

Edit: A good help to find such issues: `https://<your Jenkins instance>/pipeline-model-converter/validate`. See for more info [Pipeline development tools](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/development/)

Comment: You, sir, are correct. And it took only two years for someone to find the answer...